# Angular with directive select and submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, select

Angular creation of a blank option in select can be very tiresome. Any solutions for this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','angularSpinners'])
.controller("StudentController",function($scope,$http,$modal){
   $scope.students=[
     {"first_name":"Miguel","last_name":"Smith","id":10},
     {"first_name":"Ann","last_name":"Jones","id":11}
   ];
   $scope.courselist=[
      {"first_name":"Dave","last_name":"Smith","id":8},
      {"first_name":"Mike","last_name":"Winner","id":9}
   ];
   $scope.sDefault=$scope.courselist[0].id;

})
.directive('thisView', function() {
   return {
     restrict:"E",
     scope: {
       students:"=",
       courselist:"=",
       sDefault:"="
   },
   templateUrl: 'this-view.html',
   controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.remStudent = function(remId) {
         $scope.students.splice( $.inArray(remId, $scope.students), 1 );
         $scope.courselist.push(data);//data will be returned from http not relevant for question
     };
     $scope.addStudent = function(addId) {//this from student list
        $scope.students.push(data);//data will be returned from http not relevant for question
        $scope.courselist.splice( $.inArray(addId, $scope.courselist), 1 );
     };     
   }
});
```

On main page:

```
<div ng-controller="StudentController">
   {{sDefault}}  //works
   <this-view students="students" courselist="courselist" sDefault="sDefault"></this-view>
</div>
```

this-view.html:

```
   {{sDefault}} //doesn't work

<form ng-submit="addStudent(addStudentId)">
           <select  class="form-control" ng-model="addStudentId" >
                <option value="" selected>Default</option>
                 <option  ng-repeat="option in courselist" value="{{option.id}}" >{{option.first_name}} {{option.last_name}}</option>
               </select>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Add Student" />
 </form>
```

I have tried a select without a blank option but when I did this the model would not post on submit, so I added a default:

```
<option value="" selected>Default</option>
```

but when I submit the form the select array (courselist) is spliced and a blank option is added as well as the the default above and the remaining courselist.

Is there a way to just add the options from the courselist array (without the angular blank) and still be able to post it.

I have tried to send a default - "sDefault" but for some reason this doesn't pass into the directive.

Essentially I need to NOT have a default select, and be able to post to a form, simple you'd think?!
 ng-options are an issue because it is not a single item output i.e. {{first_name}} {{last_name}} and this again wouldn't post, anyway.

Any help appreciated.

Further info:

Thanks to Timcodes below I have found the cause of the problem but still not a solution.
[Example working without $http](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Hrv2E5DEgjn56wU0emO?p=preview)

The above code I gave was to avoid lots of $http. But I have noticed that using the real version with api creates the blank select:

```
.controller("StudentController",function($scope,$http,$modal){
   $scope.studentlist = function() {
     $http.get('/api').
       success(function(data) {
          $scope.courselist = data;
        });
   };
   $scope.studentlist();
 });
```

$scope.courselist outputs
    [{"first_name":"Miguel","last_name":"Smith","id":10}]

If I put this directly into the controller:

```
$scope.courselist=[{"first_name":"Miguel","last_name":"Smith","id":10}]
```

it works,as in the plunker example, but with the $http it creates a blank first select option.

SOLUTION: I decided to preload the courselist from the backend into a javascript variable rather than api it. This way the list was defined before creating selectedItem.

I'd be interested to hear angular solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'As' Syntax to concat two values to gather. for example ng-options = "a as (a.first + a.last) for a in alist". Also you can use ng-model to set a default. To do this initialize the ng-model to the default value, in like a activation function that is called when you controller is first ran. Then to keep blank values from appearing after you splice the array reset the ng-model to another value. for instance you could have a model called selectedCourse and then set that intially to the first course in the array of courses, then when you call the add function, after you complete any ansync stuff, then splice the array. Reset the selected to the first course in the course array again. Something like below, also have linked plunk

```
// js
app.directive('thisView', function() {
   return {
     restrict:"E",
     scope: {
       students:"=",
       courselist:"=",
   },
   templateUrl: 'thisView.html',

   controller: function($scope) {

      //intialize selected course
      $scope.selectedCourse =  $scope.courselist[0];


      $scope.remStudent = function(remId) {
         $scope.students.splice( $.inArray(remId, $scope.students), 1 );
         $scope.courselist.push(data);//data will be returned from http not relevant for question
     };
     $scope.addStudent = function() {
       // pretending this is async op that returns a promise
      $scope.students.push(data).then(function(){

          var idx =  $scope.courselist.indexOf($scope.selectedCourse);     
          $scope.courselist.splice(idx,1);

          // reset slected course
          $scope.selectedCourse =  $scope.courselist[0];
       });     

     };     
   }
  }

  //html


   <form ng-submit="addStudent()">
      <select name="test"  
       ng-options=
       "course as (course.first_name + ' ' + course.last_name)
        for  course in courselist"
        ng-model="selectedCourse" >
     </select>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Add Student" />
   </form>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

http://plnkr.co/edit/7Hrv2E5DEgjn56wU0emO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but not the main issue and this gives me only one name when I need both. This still doesn't resolve the blank option.

Comment: You can use ng-model to set defualt

Comment: $scope.courselist=[
      {"first_name":"Dave","last_name":"Smith","id":8},
      {"first_name":"Mike","last_name":"Winner","id":9}
   ];
   
    $scope.selectedItem =  $scope.courselist[0];

Comment: I have tried that before. It still doesn't pass to the directive.

Comment: give me a couple of mins Ill pull your code into a plnkr and see what i can do

Comment: Try this and let me know if it does not work for you, another option is to use the transclude function inside of your link function

Comment: thanks. Same issues as I came across, though. the blank to begin with.

Comment: Hi, apologies for disappearing. What you have done, is good and has pinpointed the cause of the problem. I have added it to the main post.

Comment: Not yet, but been busy with other things sorry, you could manipulate the data before you pass it to the directive. There is a couple of ways you can do this. are you using UI router?

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, I'm not.

Comment: Looks like you got everything working, Awesome !!. Without going into to much depth. One simple solution is in your $http success function you could loop through the JSON response and clean it up there. Another option if you were using ui-router it has a resolve block that you can essentially do the same thing. Third option is to build your own custom http interceptor. Anyway glad to here you got everything working